# Hover effect doesn't finish animation when using Fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm having problems with a hover animation when I use Fancybox.
When I click on the image and the Fancybox pops up the animation doesn't finish.

```
$(".portfolio_item > a").fancybox();

$(".portfolio_item > a img").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "slow");
    },
    function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
    });
```

It's like the animation freezes.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6aDP5/).

As you can see, if you click on the image, the Fancybox works but the image doesn't finish the animation.

How can I solve it?

Comment: can't seem to get the demo to work.

Comment: it's workin for me.Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tpkhD/) fork

Comment: i dont think its working for me

Comment: what do you mean? you dont see the fancybox? you dont see nothing? THere's a firefox image and when you "hover" it dissapears and then comes back.Thats ok, but when you click the fancybox opens and the firefox image dont return to max opacity

Comment: `GET http://fancybox.net/js/fancybox-1.3.4/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js 403 (Forbidden)` and `GET http://fancybox.net/js/fancybox-1.3.4/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css 403 (Forbidden)`.  You can't hotlink to the site it seems.  Your machine must be going off a cached version.

Comment: puff. I've created a new one with the js on my own server [New Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6aDP5/) hope it works!

Comment: @Oterox Well... mostly XD now it's just missing all the images associated with fancybox. :P  you could probably see the same thing if you clear your browser's cache.

Comment: well, that images are not needed for this problem, only the firefox one :) .... Images uploaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the problem occurs because when fancybox is trigger, the browser couldn't detect the "onmouseout" event and hence the image doesn't get fade back into opacity 1.

An easy fix would be to manually trigger the opacity reset when fancybox is triggered:

```
// Abstract out the reset function
var resetOpacity = function() {
    $(".portfolio_item a img").stop().animate({"opacity": "1"});
}

// Apply the reset on complete
$(".portfolio_item > a").fancybox({'onComplete': resetOpacity});

// Reuse the same reset function on hover out
$(".portfolio_item > a img").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "slow");
    },
    resetOpacity
);
```

You can try it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/6aDP5/2/

And here is the code to the final behavior you were looking for:
http://jsfiddle.net/6aDP5/9/

```
$(".portfolio_item > a").each(function() {
    var thisAnchor = $(this);
    var targetImg = $(this).find("img");

    var fadeOpacity = function() {
        targetImg.stop().animate({"opacity": "0"});
    }
    var resetOpacity = function() {
        targetImg.stop().animate({"opacity": "1"});
    }

    thisAnchor
        .mouseenter(fadeOpacity)
        .mouseleave(resetOpacity)
        .fancybox({
            'onStart': function() {
                thisAnchor.unbind('mouseleave');
                fadeOpacity();
            },
            'onClosed': function() {
                thisAnchor.mouseleave(resetOpacity);
                resetOpacity();
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: thats what i wanted but the firefox image shouldn't be visible until the fancybox closes.Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: yes but i need the previous effect too i mean:
1 - the image must hover always(maybe the user dont want to click it)
2 - If clicked, the fancybox opens and the image keeps its visivility 0.When the fancybox closes the image returns to opacity 1. 

So the task 2 works now but the 1 dont

Comment: It's a bit more complicated to handle the hover and the fancybox interactions, but here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/6aDP5/5/ This should be the final behavior you are looking for.

Comment: that is ..but (you're going to hate me) ... you removed the $(this) so now all the images do the same.Duplicate the <div class="portfolio_item"> to have 2 images and you could see what i mean.